# Android: leaving an app with home button and returning to a different activity when going through a long press on the home button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I have an app which has uses bluetooth, and should not be accessible if the bluetooth is turned off on the device.

the way I chose to implement this is as follows:

1. created a dispatcher activity which is launched when the app is first launched.
2. this activity checks the status of bluetooth, if bt is off, it send you to `noBtScreen`, if it is on, it takes you to `yesBtScreen`

the problem is that when the user gets to the `noBtScreen` and then hits the home button, changes the bt status and comes back to the app (by long pressing the home button and selecting my app) it arrives at the `noBtScreen` which it shouldn't get to at this point.

There are obviously naive ways to fix this, for example, I can check the bt status in the activity's `onResume`, but I think that there is a "right" solution which should be used here.

I've tried some of the activity settings in the manifest file
specifically, I tried putting the following flags on the `NoBtTask`:
`android:finishOnTaskLaunch`
`android:allowTaskReparenting` in combination and not in combination with
`android:clearTaskOnLaunch`
`android:alwaysRetainTaskState`

I also tried adding this.finish to the `noBtActivity::onStop` method, but that didn't help either (what happened then was that I got in once, got out, and when i got in again, nothing happened and i stayed on the home screen, when i tried it again, it indeed took me to the dispatcher activity, it's interesting to see the log for this:

> 09-21 17:54:49.511: INFO/ActivityManager(115): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.test.elad/.NoBtActivity } from pid 12603
>
> 09-21 17:54:49.523: ERROR/Elad(12603): NoBtActivity.onCreate
>
> 09-21 17:54:49.527: ERROR/Elad(12603): NoBtActivity.onStart
>
> 09-21 17:54:49.527: ERROR/Elad(12603): NoBtActivity.onResume
>
> 09-21 17:54:49.765: INFO/ActivityManager(115): Displayed com.test.elad/.NoBtActivity: +248ms
>
> 09-21 17:54:51.867: ERROR/Elad(12603): NoBtActivity.onSaveInstanceState
>
> 09-21 17:54:51.867: ERROR/Elad(12603): NoBtActivity.onPause
>
> 09-21 17:54:51.867: INFO/ActivityManager(115): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher } from pid 115
>
> 09-21 17:54:51.882: VERBOSE/RenderScript_jni(195): surfaceCreated
>
> 09-21 17:54:51.882: VERBOSE/RenderScript_jni(195): surfaceChanged
>
> 09-21 17:54:52.277: ERROR/Elad(12603): NoBtActivity.onStop
>
> 09-21 17:54:56.183: INFO/ActivityManager(115): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.test.elad/.DispatcherActivity } from pid 115
>
> 09-21 17:54:56.265: ERROR/Elad(12603): NoBtActivity.onDestroy

Comment: What do you mean by "what happened then was that I got in once, got out, and when i got in again, nothing happend and i stayed on the home screen, when i tried it again, it indeed took me to the dispatcher activity"? Can you explain to me .. because the normal chain must be different and must work as expected

Comment: Moved this to an answer instead of being a comment

Comment: Have you tried to register in `noBtActivity` a `BroadcastReceiver` for `ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` and finish the activity there on bluetooth turned on?

Answer (score 1):

Put `android:noHistory="true"` in Manifest for both `noBtScreen` and `yesBtScreen`.

Here's what the android docs says about noHistory:

> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical
>   trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the
>   user will not be able to return to it.

**EDIT:**

I have another suggestion that hopefully will work.

When you `startActivity` from your dispatcher Activity, you could pass an extra with the key name `"randomExtra"`

Then in the `onResume` or `onCreate` of your other Activities check if `intent.hasExtra("randomExtra")`, and then if that returns true, then just continue. If it returns false, then do `startActivity(new Intent(context, DispatcherActivity.class)`

Comment: that doesn't work, i get the same behavior as i got when i put the finish in onStop:
go in app with bt off
press home button
long press home button and select the app
expected result - return to app
actual result - nothing happens
in the log i see that when i call the app the second time it gets to the onstop and then ondestroy...

Comment: I would just do away with the activity that is called at first, and just put the bt check in both your bt on and bt off activities.

Comment: the example i gave in the question is a simplification of the actual situation - it's not really as simple as that and that's why I can't remove the dispatcher activity

Answer (score 1):

Call `finish()` in `onUserLeaveHint()` callback of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify android:launchMode="singleTask" in manifest for your dispatcher activity.

Answer (score 0):

First if you are going to put your finish() anywhere it would be in the onPause() method. onPause is called immediately after moving out of the actively showing activity.

With that said you need to check these intent flags out... more specifically look at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Edit: also here is a flag that is set by the system that you can check to see if the activity was launched from the activity stack history: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY

Edit2: WOW I see some really complex answers! The OP needs to do no more than make sure that the activity cannot be called again unless a conditional says so. An Intent flag is plenty to perform this task.

Don't over-complicate things!!!

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question exactly, as it suggests a different approach, but hopefully it will at least be useful for other viewers. Here's what I would do:

The application initially launches a (`BluetoothEnforcerActivity`), which is a blank screen.  In its `onResume()`, check the status of Bluetooth.  If Bluetooth is not available, show an alert dialog informing the user that Bluetooth must be enabled to continue.  The dialog would have the buttons "Quit" and "Try Again".

"Quit" would of course exit the dialog and the `BluetoothEnforcerActivity` (bringing the user back to the home screen).  "Try again" would exit the dialog such that `BluetoothEnforcerActivity` would test for Bluetooth again in `onResume()`.  (If Bluetooth is still not available, just show the dialog again.  Make sure there's enough of a pause that the user can tell the dialog closed and re-opened.)

If/when Bluetooth is finally available, the `BluetoothEnforcerActivity` launches the main activity and calls its own finish() method.

All that said, don't forget to consider the case where the user disables Bluetooth once they've gotten past the `BluetoothEnforcerActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you is to create a new class that extend from Activity (BTActivity)
and make both NoBtActivity and YesBtActivity extend from BTActivity.

Now, on BTActivity Override onRestart and check for the bluetooth status in there, if it's on and you are on NoBtActivity, change to YesBtActivity and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Try something lik this:

1. Register `BroadcastReceiver` for `android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED` (check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)), it will notify you when the Bluetooth has been turned on or off.
2. On your `onReceive()` method of `BroadcastReceiver` store it's position. You can use sharedpreference for this.
3. When your `noBtScreen` comes to foreground, override `onResume()` method and check for this variable and if the `bluetooth` is on then `startactivity(yesBtScreen)` and finish() the `noBtScreen`.
4. You can put same check on `yesBtScreen` and if the `bluetooth` is off then `startactivity(noBtScreen)` and finish() the `yesBtScreen`.

Answer (score 0):

I made an app that had a login screen at the start. Leaving the application and returning would mean going back to the login screen. This is how I got around it - it required the use of intents to save data. (I have 4 activities - Main Activity, second actvity, login setup activity and login activity)

on the main activity i have this:

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    super.onUserLeaveHint();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String activity = intent.getStringExtra("activity");
    if (activity == null || !activity.equals("first") || !activity.equals("firsttime")){
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(MainActivity.this);
    }else {
        getIntent().removeExtra("activity");
    }
    System.out.println("mainactivity");
}
```

on my second activity i have this:

```
private void returning(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("activity","first");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and on my login setup activity I have this (on the onclick for login):

```
    Intent i = new Intent(LoginSetup.this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("activity","firsttime");
    startActivity(i);
```

So every time I move between activities something is stored in the intent extras and when I leave the activity the intent is checked to see if it holding intent data. If the intent is holding no extras then you return to the login screen.

hope this helps.